# How to call Leidos FSS from Alaskan phone number

Tags: cell-phone, fss

My cell phone has an Alaskan area code (907).  When I call 1-800-wxbrief, the automated voice says that I have reached the "Juneau Flight Service Station," even when I am located in Florida.

Has anyone encountered this?  Does anyone know of a way to tell it to direct me to the proper FSS for my location (regardless of my phone number)?

Comment: I would suggest staying on the call until someone at Juneau FSS answers, and then asking them if they know of a direct number for Leidos FSS.

Comment: Isn't automation wonderful?  It solves all our problems...

Comment: They should have an automated message that says "State your location" or something along those lines and you either say "North Florida" or "South Florida" depending on your location. I haven't had any issues with my MA phone number in contacting FSS in FL.